# How to set multiple value from EditText to 1 Textview and Automaticaly show without click Button

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Is it possible to set multiple from EditText to 1 Textview and automatically show without click any button. Here is the XML sample.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/labelnim"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:text="Name :"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text" >

        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/labelnama"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="Spesification"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/spesification"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:inputType="text"
            >

        </EditText>

           <TextView
           android:id="@+id/TextView Output"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/labelnama"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="Output"
            android:textSize="18sp" />



</LinearLayout>
```

I want the data show in TextViewOutput as with Name + Specification. Also when I'm typing the output automatically change to whenever I type in Both EditText

Comment: yes you can don it by using `addTextChangedListener` but its difficult to manage two outputs in same View so i will suggest you to take two textViews like output1 and putput2 in horizontal view

Comment: see my answer..it will be helpful for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thankyou for helping me. All of you such an amazing person. Here is the code

First 2 value or more from EditText show in 1 Textview

```
TextView output.setText(Name.getText().toString()+"-"+Spesicification.getText().toString()"-"+MoreOuput.getText().toString());
```

And For Automated Text you are right with TextWatcher

```
 Name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String name = NamaAlat.getText().toString();
            if(name!=null){
                TextView output.setText(Name.getText().toString()+"-"+Spesicification.getText().toString()"-"+MoreOuput.getText().toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    Spesification.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String spek = NamaAlat.getText().toString();
            if(spek!=null){
                TextView output.setText(Name.getText().toString()+"-"+Spesicification.getText().toString()"-"+MoreOuput.getText().toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Thankyou so much.

Comment: if the answer was helpful..upvote the answer and also mark it as verified

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure, you have to user `addTextChangedListener` Follow the below code

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
   }

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
  String editValue = editText.getText().toString();
  if(editValue.lenght!=0){
  String textValue = yourTextView.getText().toString();
  int val = Integer.parse(textValue);
  int edVal = Integer.parse(editValue);

  int result = edVal * val;

  resultText.setText(result);

  }

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
}
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to maintain two different `addOnTextChangeListerner's` output in same textView so it is better to **Replace** your layout section with -

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/labelnama"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_Output1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:text="Output"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_Output2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and apply `addTextChangedListener` on both **editText** and set their outputs in respective **TextViews**...like this

```
    final EditText nameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    final EditText spesificationEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.spesification);
    final TextView textViewOutput1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Output1);
    final TextView textViewOutput2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Output2);

    nameEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String name = nameEditText.getText().toString();
            if(name!=null){
                textViewOutput1.setText(name);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    spesificationEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String specification = spesificationEditText.getText().toString();
            if(specification!=null){
                textViewOutput2.setText(specification);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

}
```